# How do I do selection sort?

Tags: python, sorting

`numbers = list (input("Please enter your numbers: "))`

`print (numbers)`

This is all I have when I start the code it only shows single digit numbers but when I put 12, I get '1' '2' how do I make it stay 12 and sort the numbers smallest to biggest?

Comment: You need to `split` this into a list of strings then convert the strings to integers.

Comment: @DimitrijeCriric HEY! Got the 12 to stay 12 thanks! how would identify the smallest number of the list and move it to the begining? isnt it min(numbers) to indentify the smallest?

Answer (score 1):

`input("Please enter your numbers: ")` - this returns string

`list(string)` - will separate string on every character and make list of them

I think this will do what you want:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter your numbers: ").split(' ')]
print (numbers)
```

I used `split()` function, and when i say `string.split(' ')` it will separate string on every **`' '`** and return the list.
For sorting the list you can use the built-in function [`sort()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort), or you can make your own. [This page](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/selection-sort) will help you to make your sorting function with **selection sort**.

Comment: You probably also want to `map` those to `int` or it will sort `'12'` before `'2'`...